# Ref with objects

Tags: f#, unity-game-engine

```
namespace FsharpUnity
open UnityEngine

type DebugTest() = 
    inherit MonoBehaviour()
    member this.Update() = 
       let m = Input.mousePosition
       let look = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(m)
       let mutable r = new RaycastHit()
       if Physics.Raycast(look, ref r,1000.0f ) then
           Debug.Log("I hit: " + r.point.ToString())
       ()
```

I am currently trying to use F# with Unity3d and I am not sure how I would use the ref keyword with objects.

I tried it with

```
let mutable r = new RaycastHit() // Is this incorrect?
           if Physics.Raycast(..., ref r,....) then
```

But the `r`is always empty which seems a little bit strange. There was no example of how I would use the ref keyword with objects on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx

Did I make a mistake?

To clarify my question: Is this the correct syntax?

```
let mutable r = new RaycastHit()
... ref r ....
```

Comment: Most of the time you use either `mutable` or `ref` but not both. You could do `let r = ref (new RayCastHit())` which creates an immutable pointer to a reference cell containing the instance. That's the right way to use `ref` but I'm not sure it would be compatible with the Unity call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just add the & char to the beginning of your r variable
such that....

```
let mutable r = new RaycastHit()

Physics.Raycast(look, &r,1000.0f )
```

[see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx)

OR ....

You could use what is considered the "functional way" and be without any variables("mutable")

[source](http://fpish.net/topic/Some/5/58537)
Functions with out parameters are treated as tuple types with the return type so you could use your example like so:

```
let (result, result_of_b_param) = function 3
let (result, int_value) = Int32.TryParse "3"

match Int32.TryParse "23" with
| (true, x) -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

You can use the the attribute 
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute` on function parameters:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type foo () =
member x.Foo ([] y : int32 ref) =
y := 0
```